# How to copy from primitive type variables when passing through rvalue reference function arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, rvalue-reference, primitive-types, lvalue

I can copy from a non-primitive type variable by copy constructor and pass it through rvalue reference function argument.

But how can do this with primitive type variables?

for example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
struct MyClass
{
   int m = 0;
};
MyClass& f(MyClass& x)
{
   x.m++;
   return x;
}
inline MyClass f(MyClass&& x)
{
   return f(x);
}
int& f(int& x)
{
   x++;
   return x;
}
inline int f(int&& x)
{
   return f(x);
}
int main()
{
   MyClass x1;
   auto y1 = f(MyClass(x1)); // Calls f(MyClass&&)
   // Result: x1.m = 0, y1.m = 1

   int x2 = 0;
   auto y2 = f(int(x2)); // Calls f(int&)
   // Result: x2 = 1, y2 = 1

   std::cout << x1.m << x2; // Result in VS2013: '01' But '00' in gcc and clang!
   assert(x1.m == x2); // FAILED in VS2013!!!
   return 0;
}
```

The result in Visual Studio 2013 is '01' with assertion failed.

http://rextester.com/CAPY87169

Comment: I don't have VS2013, but what happens if you do this: auto y2 = f(int x3=x2); ?

Comment: @IanThompson error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and this seems to be a bug in VS2013.

Simpler MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int& x)  { std::cout << "f(lv)\n"; }
void f(int&& x) { std::cout << "f(rv)\n"; }

int main()
{
   int x2 = 0;
   f( int(x2) );
   f( (int)x2 );
}
```

Output should be:

```
f(rv)
f(rv)
```

[MSVC online tester](http://rextester.com/CLIAX67021)

Note that further testing shows that the bug is really that `(int)x2` is treated as an lvalue by MSVC; it's not a bug with MSVC's extension to allow rvalues to bind to lvalue references (since the rvalue reference is a better match anyway).

You may be able to fix this by using the `/Za` switch.

---

The expression `int(x2)` is covered by C++14 [expr.type.conv]/2 (C++11 has the same numbering):

> A *simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2)* or *typename-specifier (14.6)* followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4).

The corresponding cast expression is:

> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**.