# Is the result of a cast an rvalue?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, standards, lvalue

Let

```
int a = 0;
```

Then is `(int)a` an *rvalue* in standard C++?

Different compilers show different results for this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int& x)
{
    cout << "l value" << endl;
}

void f(int&& x)
{
    cout << "r value" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    f((int)a);
}
```

compilers with different results:

1) http://cpp.sh/2r6

2) http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Has anyone checked to see if there is a [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) bug yet? A cursory search did not turn one up.

Comment: @Mgetz I was looking, I have not found anything obvious though.

Comment: [Filed as a defect on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1008261) against VS2013 using @ShafikYaghmour's test case

Comment: It's a long-standing "feature" of MSVC that a temporary is allowed to bind to a non-const reference. Turn it off with [`/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) option.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik well it's filed as a bug now, MS can decide to keep or remove that extension at their discretion. However their compiler is non-conforming if they leave it enabled by default.

Comment: [Similar thread from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480413/how-to-copy-from-primitive-type-variables-when-passing-through-rvalue-reference/26481317#26481317)

Comment: note: removed the language-lawyer tag as no lawyering is required , it's black and white; and added "visual-c++" and "lvalue" tag as I'm sure the same issue is responsible for a lot of other thigns.

Comment: MS has finally responded, this is apparently controlled by [/Zc:rvalueCast (Enforce type conversion rules)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449507.aspx) they have marked my bug as fixed. I'm still seeking clarification on if this will be turned on by default in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The should be an *rvalue* but *webcompiler* is running Visual Studio and Visual Studio has an <s>[extension which allows temporary objects to be bound to non-const lvalue references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20851672/1708801).</s> [a bug/extension that casues it to generate an *lvalue* in this case](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/615622) As Igor points out above this can be disabled using `/Za` (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/AFMJOB19305)*).

We can see that it should be an *rvalue*(*specifically a prvalue*) from the draft C++ standard section `5.4` *Explicit type conversion (cast notation)* paragraph *1* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue
>   reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference
>   to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue.**[ Note: if T is
>   a non-class type that is cv-qualified, the cv-qualifiers are ignored
>   when determining the type of the resulting prvalue; see 3.10. —end
>   note ]

Both [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ab84e72708417a) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/011c00e1b6e5b022) result in *rvalue* which is the expected result.

As an aside, I would recommend using [rextester](http://rextester.com/) over *webcompiler* since rextester allows you to share your program and also has live sharing.

**Update**

Ben Voigt point out this [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/615622) and so it seems that Visual Studio actually produces an *lvalue*. So this is not simply a case of the [extension which allows temporary objects to be bound to non-const lvalue references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20851672/1708801).

As dyp points out [gcc used to have a cast to lvalue extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html) as well.

**Update 2**

Mgetz filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1008261), the response was that this is fixed by using the [/Zc:rvalueCast flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449507.aspx), the description of the flag is as follows:

> When the /Zc:rvalueCast option is specified, the compiler correctly
>   identifies an rvalue reference type as the result of a cast operation
>   in accordance with the C++11 standard. When the option is not
>   specified, the compiler behavior is the same as in Visual Studio 2012.
>   By default, /Zc:rvalueCast is off. For conformance and to eliminate
>   errors in the use of casts, we recommend that you use /Zc:rvalueCast.

It is unclear whether this flag will be enabled by default in future versions.

Comment: +1 for your recommendation. how long does the live sharing link lives?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus not sure, I have only used for short periods and th site does not document it.

Comment: This answer is wrong, actually.  Visual C++ isn't using the misfeature that binds an lvalue reference to a temporary.... it is completely failing to create a temporary at all.  See Matt's answer and my bug report https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/615622

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for sharing that link, it is odd though that using `/Za` fixes it so this no longer seems to be the default behavior and in fact when I use `/Za` this `(int)a = 2 ;` is an error. I will add your reference to my answer.

Comment: The language extension that binds an rvalue to an lvalue-reference only works if there *is* an object; that's not true for prvalues of fundamental types http://rextester.com/TOJWJL48414. Strangely, gcc once had a similar "extension" that allowed the result of a cast to be used as an lvalue: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html (cast-as-lvalue)

Comment: @dyp that is odd, do you know what the use case for this is?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour For the MSVC or the GCC extension?

Comment: @dyp for casting to an lvalue which `gcc` used to have and `MSVC` still does.

Comment: I can only hypothesize that `(char) i = 5;` is more convenient to write than `*((char*)&i) = 5;` (in C). You can find some discussion when searching for "cast-as-lvalue". E.g. it seems to have been in early C89 drafts.

Comment: @BenVoigt hmm maybe they'll finally fix it with my bug report.

Comment: @Mgetz if you let me know when you receive an update, I will also update my answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour MS has resolved the bug as fixed, apparently we were all wrong: [/Zc:rvalueCast (Enforce type conversion rules)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449507.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the result of a cast to an object type is an *rvalue*, as specified by C++11 5.4/1:

> The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference
>   type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**.

Comment: The key is that there is no rule making an exception for a cast from `T` to `T`.

Answer (score 5):

In Standard C++ `int(a)` and `(int)a` are rvalues (the other answers provide standard references).

Your code example is exploiting a bug/extension in MSVC, but not what it seems like at first glance. As we can see from this code which works in MSVC:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    (int)x = 1;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

MSVC treats `(int)x` as an lvalue.

Even though MSVC has an extension to allow rvalues to bind to non-const references; that extension still makes rvalue references a better match than lvalue references for rvalues.

Comment: I reported this and several other variants on Connect four years ago: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/615622